# Closing Resultset and statement

Tags: java, database

Can any one help on the issue encountered in the following piece of code. It seems that DB connection is lost when trying to execute the query in section 2.

```
 String query = "SELECT .....";
    try {
      con=getConnection();

      String query1 ="SELECT....";

      stmt = con.prepareStatement(query1);

      rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(query1);  -- Section1
      while (rs1.next()) {
      }
       **Close resultset;
       Close statement;**

      stmt = con.prepareStatement(query); -- Section 2
      rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

I suspect db connection is lost in section 2. Is this due to the close resultset and statement placed before executing Section2? Please advise.

Regards,
Steven

Comment: Is this a contest where we have to guess the programming lanugage you're using here? I'll go with Java then! Also you didn't declare *query* anywhere...

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace and a description of what the error is?

Answer (score 2):

Close the resultset and statement in a `finally` block, or at the end of your code.

Comment: To: m0skit0 -> Sorry, I forgot to specify the language. Yes, Its Java. I feel Query is not important here. Any select statement will be appropriate on this scenario. My query is that is it not a good practice to have close resultset and statement before executing another query.

Comment: To: beny23 -> Sorry, I am not able to provide the stacktrace since the logs are overwritten every 5 minutes...From the other logs, i noticed that exception occurred when the program tried executing the section 2 stmt = con.prepareStatement(query); -- Section 2

Comment: To: Sean -> Thanks for the suggestion. Lemme try out that.

Comment: Without info from stack traces or logs, that's most likely your problem :)